# "how to fix MathJax linebreaking?"

Tags: line-breaks, mathjax

I'm using doubleslash(\\) for line-breaking ,the cursor is pointing to the next line but a single slash(\) is appending with my data.

This is the input I am giving:

> Find the median of the given data:"\\ "13, 16, 12, 14, 19, 12, 14, 13, 14"

The output is:

> Find the median of the given data: \13, 16, 12, 14, 19, 12, 14, 13, 14.

Single slash is appending to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\\\\`.  Your content management system may be using `\` as a special character, an that may turn `\\` into `\` in the resulting HTML.  For example, Markdown usually does that.